# The probability that at least one box contains only one ball.

Tags: probability, combinations

There are $X$ boxes and $Y$ players, each player has $Z$ balls. ($X\geq Z$)

Now each player randomly chooses $Z$ out of $X$ boxes, and puts one ball in each chosen box. After all players completed the above actions, what is the probability that at least one box contains only one ball?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I only tried the probability that one specific box contains only one ball, this is quite trivial. But it's really hard to get the probability that at least one box contains only one ball, since numbers of balls in different boxes are not independent.